# why does printf("a" "b" "c") prints abc in C

Tags: c

I have the following code in C:

```
#include<stdio.h>
void main(){
    printf("a" "b" "c");
}
```

it outputs:

**`abc`**

Can anyone explain why?

I am guessing that it is `"a" "b" "c"` preprocessed as `"abc"`. Am I right or Is it something else?

Comment: 5.1.1.2 Translation phases 6 _Adjacent string literal tokens are concatenated._

Comment: +1 it is a good question, unless you know the terminology it is probably hard to figure out.

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour can I humbly request that since this question has a better title, and a slightly more detailed answer, that it stay open?  If it is closed then people searching for questions will not find it, and they may not look at something titled "Isn't there a syntax error?".

Comment: @MattMcNabb that is a very good point, I reworded the question and the title and so it should be in better shape now.

Comment: @MattMcNabb: people can still search for this even if it's marked as duplicate, no point fragmenting everything IMO (that's the reason we have the duplicate system). There's a reason they show up as "duplicate" rather than just "closed".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Adjacent string literals are concatenated as part of *translation phase 6*.

Brief summary of phases (source: C99 standard, paraphrased)

1. Trigraphs and multi-byte characters in the source file are mapped to the source character set
2. Lines ending in `\` are spliced
3. File parsed into a set of preprocessing tokens
4. Preprocessing directives processed
5. Character constants and string literals are migrated to the execution character set
6. Adjacent string literals are concatenated.
7. The rest of compilation (excluding linking)
8. Linking

Comment: So the guess made by OP at the end of the question is almost accurate, right?

Comment: so in short **it is done during `preprocessing`**. I guess I was guessing it right :D. Thanks! I was expecting such kind of answer.

Comment: @barakmanos Depends whether or not you want to call phase 6 "preprocessing". `gcc -E` does not do phase 6.

Comment: This is quite a good answer, I have to say.

Comment: @MattMcNabb yes! thanks for mentioning `gcc -E` I knew it wrong according to the syntax of `printf()`. it now gives compilation error.

Comment: @SMR it's probably worth mentioning too that (like with anything in the C standard), the compiler doesn't have to actually process these steps in that order -- so long as the final output of your program is the same as it would have been if the steps were processed in that order. For example it could prune whitespace (normally part of phase 7) and then concatenate string literals and it would make no difference.

Answer (score 4):

Adjacent string literals are merged in <s>compilation</s> *translation phase* 6. Since `"a" "b" "c"` is further treated as `"abc"` string literal.

In case of you are not familiar with this term, phase 6 is somewhat between preprocessing and actual, "proper" compilation.

Comment: To be really language-lawyerish, it is "translation" not "compilation"

Comment: @WojtekSurowka: Absolutely right, corrected.

Comment: Nice, I just learnt something new today! http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/translation_phases

Comment: Wouldn't it be true to say that the guess made by OP at the end of the question is correct (i.e., doesn't that take place during preprocessing)?

Comment: @barakmanos: That's after preprocessing.

Comment: @Deduplicator: OK, I just realized that from reading the other answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Because you're doing [String literal concatenation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_syntax#String_literal_concatenation)

the resulting cstring passed to printf is `"abc\0"`